# Turning all sheet tabs properties of a single Google sheet workbook into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, google-sheets-api

When you request a workbook using:

`rsp = service.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId=key).execute()`

you get a very difficult to read nested dictionary with all of the workbook properties.

I want to make a pandas dataframe of the sheets by position of sheet or `index` going down, and properties going across... such as `title` and `id` .... etc.

The result would look something like this

```
index   title      id   ....    
0       sheet1    ...
1         ...
2         ... 
3         ...
```

would be alot easier to work with once in this format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve all properties from all sheets in a Google Spreadsheet.
- You want to put the retrieved values to the dataframe.
- You want to achieve this using googleapis with python.
- You have already been able to get values from Spreadsheet using Sheets API.

For this, how about this answer?

In this case, the following flow is used.

1. Retrieve the properties of all sheets in a Spreadsheet using the method of spreadsheets.get in Sheets API.

   - In the current stage, all properties of a sheet are `'index', 'title', 'sheetId', 'sheetType', 'gridProperties.rowCount', 'gridProperties.columnCount'`.
2. Create the dataframe using the retrieved values.

#### Sample script:

```
key = "###"  # Please set the Spreadsheet ID.

service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
rsp = service.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId=key, fields='sheets(properties)').execute()
headers = ['index', 'title', 'sheetId', 'sheetType', 'gridProperties.rowCount', 'gridProperties.columnCount']
values = [[s['properties'][h] if '.' not in h else s['properties'][h.split('.')[0]][h.split('.')[1]] for h in headers] for s in rsp['sheets']]
df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=headers)
```

- In this case, I used `sheets(properties)` as the fields.

#### Result:

When above script is run, the following sample result is retrieved.

```
   index   title     sheetId sheetType  gridProperties.rowCount  gridProperties.columnCount
0      0  Sheet1           0      GRID                     1000                          26
1      1  Sheet2       #####      GRID                     1000                          26
2      2  Sheet3       #####      GRID                     1000                          26
.
.
.
```

#### Note:

- If you want to change the header, for example please modify `df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=headers)` as follows.

  ```
  df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=['index', 'title', 'id', 'type', 'rowCount', 'columnCount'])
  ```

#### References:

- [googleapis for python](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client)
- [Method: spreadsheets.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get)

Comment: Perfect. Hope others find it useful also.

Comment: @jason Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.